# Update app.yaml when updating php55 to php74 in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

Currently my **Google App Engine** project is using `php55`, but since this version is no longer supported by the community, I need to update the `app.yaml` file to use the [php74 runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/runtime).

These are the current URL handlers from the `app.yaml` file for `php55`:

```
- url: /([^/]+\.php)
  script: \1

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
  login: required
  secure: always
```

These URL handlers throw an error when I specify the `php74` runtime:

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT: script field for handler '/([^/]+\.php)' must be set to 'auto' for runtime php74.
INVALID_ARGUMENT: script field for handler '/.*' must be set to 'auto' for runtime php74.
```

When I make the suggested fixes and change the URL handlers in the `app.yaml`for `php74`:

```
- url: /([^/]+\.php)
  script: auto

- url: /.*
  script: auto
  login: required
  secure: always
```

This returns the following error: `ResourceNotFoundException: No routes found...`

What am I doing wrong with these URL handlers?  My project works with the `php55` version of the URL handlers, but not when I specify `script: auto` in the `php74` version of the `app.yaml` file.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/php-differences#migrating_your_appyaml_file), to migrate you app.yaml properly, you must place a [front controller](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/runtime#app_startup) to handle all the routing. Here is the example provided by the documentation if you are migrating from a legacy app:

```
switch (@parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path']) {
    case '/':
        require 'homepage.php';
        break;
    case '/contact.php':
        require 'contact.php';
        break;
    default:
        http_response_code(404);
        exit('Not Found');
}
```

Also I suggest that you check that you are not using a deprecated element in your app.yaml, there will be an error if you use any.
Finally if anything of this works I recommend that you check [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/config/appref) to see if there is anything wrong with your app.yaml that you didn't notice.

Comment: Thanks @drauedo , you are indeed correct.  The issue was the I needed to use a front controller to handle all the routing.